# Physical significance of $s$-sparse and efficiently row computable Hermitian matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, hamiltonian-formalism, computational-physics, linear-algebra

In section II of [Quantum algorithm for solving linear systems of equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3171) by Harrow et al, the authors defined the matrix $A$ as $s$-sparse and efficiently row computable. $s$-sparse means having at most $s$ non-zero entries per row and efficiently computable means  given a row index these entries can be computed in time $O (s)$.

**My question:**
When a Hermitian matrix fulfills these two conditions, what does it mean physically?

Comment: Most likely it means nothing at all. "Sparsity" is heavily basis dependent. Either a particular basis means something to you and then maybe (maybe!) you can interpret sparsity some way, but usually it doesn't. Just note that the most important physical basis is the one where the matrix is sparsest: the basis of eigenvectors...